# to deploy encrypted app.config windows application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have to deploy a windows application developed in Visual studio 2010 express edition.
i am using a web service to run this application. I have encrypted the Username, password and the webservice Url in config file i have followed http://ozkary.blogspot.in/2013/03/encrypting-aspnet-application-settings.html to encrypt the config file.
It works fine in my machine and other machine if i run the asp.net regiis command.
How do i deploy this application in my client machine where visual studio is not installed.

Comment: Hi Susanna,  Can I ask why you have not considered using a trusted connection.  It is the better way to do it.

Comment: i agree but i am supposed to use a web service in my application

Comment: What framework version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It is a function of .NET.  You will most likely need to make sure it is installed by looking under "Add Remove Windows Features" on the server - whatever version you happen to be using - Application Server.

You can also look at using DISM to install/check .Net framework.  It is along the lines of:

```
Dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3 /All /Source:x:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess
```